# react native AndroidManifest not effect

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest

i am a new react native, i am developing voice sip app on android,
this is required 2 permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

full permision as below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- Telephony permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />

<!--Telephony tablet permissions -->
<uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

i had already insert these lines into the AndroidManifest.xml file.
but when i release apk and install to my physical phone(samsung j5), i receive a message :
"Do you want to install this application? it does not require any special access."
then i press "Accept install".

but i check in my code :

```
var granted = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.USE_SIP);
```

//=>  granted is false =>?? why?

about microphone, after i install apk on my samsung j5 phone, i check permissions granted for this app, i saw the microphone is disabled.=> why?

Please help me, Thanks you very much.